# rel="tag"on conditional filters against keyword stuffing?

Tags: html, ajax, microformats

i use filters/tags on my webapp to sort articles dynamically. now these filteres do not really match microformat.org's idea of rel="tag" (no url, not a tag, i don't know), but i don't see any other way to avoid google seeing it as keyword stuffing.

is there a better way so highlight these "tags" or would you
encourage me to use rel="tag".

see it yourself: http://www.rewow.de/eiweisspulver/

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking one of the "tags" changes the content of the page using JavaScript.

Your JavaScript should be [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

They should be links with URLs and if the JavaScript fails, then you can generate the same content on the server. (You can use `pushState` to make the address bar match the target page when you successfully transform the current one into it with JS).

That way they match microformat.org's idea of rel="tag", and your site is more reliable and search engine friendly.